# Symfony3: Getting a session ID in a Monolog processor

Tags: php, session, symfony, monolog

For a Symfony 3.2 project I'm working on, I want to add a unique token to all log entries that belong to a specific request. The Symfony documentation happens to have an exact example for this use case using Processors (http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/processors.html). What this does is add a unique token, based on the first 8 characters of the User's session ID and the last 8 characters of a randomly generated UUID, to the log record. Precisely what I'm looking for.

However, when examining the logs, The first part of the token, which is based off the session ID (`$this->session->getId()`), is empty. This is because the Session object that was injected isn't started yet. It should be, since the request I logged was for a page only accessible with valid authentication. My guess is, the processor is being run before the session was started. I feel that starting the session in the Processor class if `$this->session->isStarted()` returns false is a dirty solution and is not the way to go (however, it gets the job done).

How can I be sure the Session object is started before the Monolog processor adds the token to the log record?